# C# Moq Mocking a method that expects a Func<TResult> delegate

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, moq, func

I need to setup a method with Moq so that I can control what it returns.  The setup I'm trying to do looks like this:

`Setup(x => x.DoSomething<TResult>(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<Func<TResult>>()).Returns(10)`

However I'm getting the following error:

The type or namespace name 'TResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

The original method that I'm trying to setup, which I did not create, recognizes TResult but it's not defined or referenced anywhere as far as I can tell.

This says it's part of the system namespace which I'm referencing in my test class so I'm confused why the test class doesn't seem to know what TResult is:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-1?view=net-7.0

I've tried to use:
`It.IsAnyType' 'Is.IsAny<Delegate>()' and variations of 'It.IsAny<Action<string>>()`

but nothing seems to satisfy the compiler.

*edit* the original method signature is the signature is:
`public TResult DoSomething<TResult>( string, int, Func<TResult> DoSomethingElse)`

*Edit* someone suggested this https://andersmalmgren.com/2021/02/28/mock-and-callback-a-generic-method-with-unavailable-type-using-moq/ and then closed my question.  I don't see how that suggestion is relevant to my issue.  I don't have as specific event to mock like "onEvent".

Comment: `TResult` is a generic parameter name. It's not a type. What is the signature of `DoSomething`?

Comment: https://andersmalmgren.com/2021/02/28/mock-and-callback-a-generic-method-with-unavailable-type-using-moq/

Comment: @Pawel Lukasik sorry I thought the setup indicated the signature of the method so I didn't include it, the signature is:

public TResult DoSomething<TResult>(
   string, int, Func<TResult> DoSomethingElse)

Comment: @RobertHarvey your links seems to suggest using  It.IsAny<Action<It.IsAnyType>>() but I get this error when I try that.

The type arguments for method 'DoSomething<TResult>(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<Func<TResult>>()' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: @mpmarven `TResult` in the prototype is a _placeholder_, the error suggests that the specific _type_ cannot be inferred, so you need to put the specific _type_ that you are trying to moq. We can't really tell you what that type might be without you posting your actual code.